# Why is it possible to sometimes attach ref to a stateless function?

Tags: reactjs, redux

From the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) (my italics):

> *Refs may not be attached to a stateless function, because the component does not have a backing instance*. You can always wrap a stateless component in a standard composite component and attach a ref to the composite component.

And the [0.14 changelog](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html) (my italics):

> Since no component instance is created for a functional component, any *ref added to one will evaluate to null*. Functional components do not have lifecycle methods, but you can set .propTypes and .defaultProps as properties on the function.

In lecture 21 of Dan Abramov's [Redux egghead tutorials](https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux), we write the following **stateless functional component** for adding a todo:

```
const AddTodo = ({
  onAddClick,
}) => {
  let input;
  return <div>
    <input ref = {node => {
        input = node;
      }} />

    <button onClick = {() => {
          onAddClick(input.value)
          input.value='';
        }}>Add Todo</button>

  </div>
}
```

**This actually works when put in to the composite component of the app and ref did not return `null` as promised by the React docs!**

Implementation of `AddTodo` in the composite component looks like this:

```
class TodoApp extends Component {

  render() {
    //console.log(store.getState());
    log();
    const {
      todos,
      visibilityFilter,
    } = this.props;
    const visibleTodos = getVisibleTodos(
      todos,
      visibilityFilter
    );
    return (
      <div>
          <AddTodo onAddClick = {
              (input) => {
                store.dispatch({
                  type:'ADD_TODO',
                  text: input,
                  id: nextTodoId++,
                })
              }
            }/>
```

The docs do say that we can wrap the stateless component in a composite component and attach a ref *to the composite component*. The key here being the attachment to the composite component, but my ref is still attached to the stateless `AddTodo` in my implementation.

My questions are:

1. `AddTodo` here really is a stateless functional component, is that not right?
2. If not, why not? (It definitely looks like one but I may be missing the salient features of what it means to be stateless)
3. If yes to question 1, then how is the behavior of being able to use a `ref` here consistent with what's being presented in the React docs?

Comment: If I had to guess, it would be that the docs refer to `ref` the prop not `ref` the callback function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ad 1) Yes, `AddTodo` is a stateless functional component.

Ad 2) nothing to do here :-)

Ad 3) You are adding the ref to the `input`, not to the `AddTodo` - that's why it works. If you look in the docs page you quoted,

> When attaching a ref to a DOM component like `<div />`, you get the DOM node back;

and that's exactly what you want in your code.

What you **cannot** do is this: `<AddTodo ref={component => ...} />` because there is no instance of `AddTodo` that could be passed to the ref function.